# how can read column data from gridview readonly column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to read the column value of gridview read only column.but it makes error as
**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values** the following is my code in rowupdate event in asp.net gridview

```
 protected void branchgrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            comp.ADMISSIONNUMBER = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AdmissionNumber"));
        //comp.ADMISSIONNUMBER = Convert.ToInt32(studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]
        comp.MEDIUM =Convert.ToString ((TextBox)studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Medium"));
        comp.CLASSNAME =Convert.ToString ((TextBox)studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Class"));
        comp.ACADAMICYEAR = Convert.ToString((TextBox)studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Academicyear"));
        comp.SECTIONNAME = Convert.ToChar(((TextBox)studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text.ToString());

       }
```

Comment: don't specify cell value directly using findcontrol  comp.ACADAMICYEAR = ((TextBox)studacgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].findcontrol("year")); try this code

Comment: I tried the above code as per you suggestion. but it does not get the value from the column.

Comment: you may try in rowcommand event or rowdatabound event

Comment: No.the above value need to be update in the database.so i need to get the value from row updating event.